# Регулярное выражение на выборку последнего слова из строки, содержащей определённые последовательности символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Пример строки:

```
Abc 123def<Vasya> Раз бан три LuboiNik
```

1.Должен быть ник  в уголках.
2.Перед ним любые символы кроме уголков.
3.После - пробел и любая строка со словом "бан|ban".
4.А затем одно любое сочетание латинских букв. Его надо выловить, потому скобки.

Ниже пример,

```
[^\<]+\<Vasya\> (ban|бан) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

однако консоль ругается, например если я не экранирую уголок. Но в инструкциях написано, что экранирование не дает ему быть обычным сиволом - а он мне нужен как обычный. Но без экранирования не пускает. Плюс ругается на скобки. Мне бы верный пример, а дальше разберусь.

Comment: Кавычки не забыл поставить, чтобы shell не пытался </> как перенаправление интерпретировать? Да и собственно что именно выполняешь в вопросе обозначить не помешало бы.

Comment: `.*` вокруг банов не хватает еще, и `$` в конце

Comment: [[ "Abc 123def<Vasya> Раз бан три LuboiNik" =~ [^\<]+'\<Vasya\>'.*(ban|бан).*([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" Попробовал Васю в кавычки... Никак.

Comment: С $ в конце выдает результат "k".

Comment: `.*?` после бана [жадность ограничьте](https://regex101.com/r/wYzHe2/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, вам подойдёт что-то подобное:

```
if [[ "Abc 123def<Vasya> Раз бан три LuboiNik" =~ \
  ^[^\<]+\<Vasya\>.*(бан|ban).*\ ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ]]
  then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

результат:

```
LuboiNik
```

---

ключевой момент: символы `<` и пробел должны быть предварены обратным слэшем

Comment: Благодарю! Насчет пробела даже не думал. Он вроде как обычный символ читается?

Comment: синтаксис выражения `[[ строка =~ регулярное-выражение ]]` требует, чтобы, во-первых, регулярное выражение было записано "как есть", т.е., без заключения в кавычки, а во-вторых, должно быть представлено одним токеном (т.е., не содержать "пробельных" разделителей). потому пробел, входящий в регулярное выражение, и следует "забэкспэйсить".

Comment: "в живой природе" вам, вероятно, придётся ещё и обрамить группу `(бан|ban)` пробелами (которые тоже потребуется предварить обратными слэшами), чтобы исключить совпаедения со словами "икебана", "abandon" и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Вот оно что. Буду знать, спасибо.